# Download csv from website directly into R

Tags: r, csv

I have a Shiny App program that depends on input that is user-specific in the form of a csv. Currently I have the user download it from the website, and then upload it to the Shiny App. Instead, I want the program to download the csv directly from the website (assuming the user is logged-in to the website).

Generally, I would use this method:

```
library(RCurl)
urlCSV <- getURL('https://{some url}.csv')
df <- read.csv(textConnection(urlCSV))
```

But in this case, the url does not end in .csv, so this method returns an empty string.

The url:
http://ebird.org/ebird/MyEBird?cmd=list&rtype=custom&r=world&time=life&fmt=csv

I realize this could be hard to communicate since few of you probably have eBird accounts. To try to help you understand: this link normally opens a popup that asks you if you want to open or save the file, just as a .csv url would.

Comment: This site appears to require an interactive login which means you can automate the download with a simple GET request. You can look into using something like [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html) to automatic the login process.

Comment: Thanks for this. I used `GET({url})` and it returned a response, but I'm not quite sure what to make of it. Might you be able to provide any further recommendations? Would it be helpful if I shared the response?

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. You *can't* automate with a simple GET. That GET probably just contains the login form, not the data. You need to use RSelenium to pretend to be a browsers and enter your username and password.